# WordPress revision box always shows "4 hours ago" when a new revision is created

Tags: php, wordpress, timezone

I am trying to understand why my development and production WordPress installs are showing the wrong revision time in the box at the bottom of the post edit screen. The time is correct on the actual revision screen, but not in that box.

Description of problem:

I noticed that on a post edit screen in wp-admin, the revisions box will show "X hours/minutes ago" and it is immediately 4 hours off from the current time when a new revision is created.  Definitely smells like a timezone issue.

I tracked down the WordPress core code in [wp-includes/post-template.php line 1839](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/879f43f2783863f5600153e4795bd65b9a98cbe1/wp-includes/post-template.php):

```
$revision_date_author = sprintf(
    /* translators: post revision title: 1: author avatar, 2: author name, 3: time ago, 4: date */
    __( '%1$s %2$s, %3$s ago (%4$s)' ),
    $gravatar,
    $author,
    human_time_diff( strtotime( $revision->post_modified ), current_time( 'timestamp' ) ),
    $date
);
```

I added some debug code just above this spot to verify the timezone is **America/New_York**.

It looks like **strtotime( $revision->post_modified )** returns the correct local time the post was modified.

But **current_time( 'timestamp' )** seems to be taking the local server time and then subtracting 4 hours (GMT offset) resulting in the printed time to be "4 hours ago" immediately after publishing/updating.

If you click into the revision, the revisions screen ([wp-admin/includes/revision.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/56c162fbc9867f923862f64f1b4570d885f1ff03/wp-admin/includes/revision.php)) shows the correct human_time_diff() (e.g. 1 minute ago or whatever).  I tracked down that code:

```
sprintf( __( '%s ago' ), human_time_diff( $modified_gmt, $now_gmt ) ),
```

**$now_gmt** is set at the very top of the function to **$now_gmt = time();**

So it looks like the issue is that **current_time( 'timestamp' )** is returning localtime - GMT offset.

Finally, my question: Is this a bug in WordPress? Is this intended when you specifically set the timezone to America/New_York? Or is there something else going on that I am not considering?

Cheers